# How do I publish a Dynamics CRM4 plug-in with multiple assemblies?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

My plugin DLL is really simple but references fifteen or so other DLLs. How do I register this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ways I know about are:
a)  Put the other assemblies in the GAC (I think this is SDK preferred method).  Will have to install on each client if needs to be taken online.
b)  Use ILMerge to merge all of your assemblies into one assembly.  You can deploy this to the database and have it used by your offline clients without a seperate install.

Comment: Thanks - I'll read up on ILMerge as this is going into a hosted environment with a lot of servers. It'll be easier to get everything in the database.